# [Navigation] problem: how to go to a specific location?

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all

My goal is to move my robot in gazebo to a specific location {x,y,z} coordinate. I have already investigated the navigation stack. Are there any easier way to archeive this goal?

Thank you all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65094/%5Bnavigation%5D-problem:-how-to-go-to-a-specific-location?/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) on 2013-06-14**:
Instead of putting "DESPERATE boy need help!" into the title of your question you should make a title that describes your actual problem, also try to use tags so that the people with knowledge about gazebo can find your question easier.

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-06-14**:
Hi. I modify  the title a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The navigation stack is designed to do just that.  You can control the robot with your keyboard or mouse to get there.

If you're talking about starting the robot in a specific location you can use the gazebo API calls to set the position of the model directly.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-06-14**:
good. would you mind to help me out here? http://answers.ros.org/question/65227/move_base-warn-start-position-out-out-the-global-cost-map/